# Powershell ().count output doesn't show data if counter<1

Tags: powershell

Maybe a dumb question, but I can't really understand why this is happening.

Simple PS script - to count AD user groups. But for users who is member of the primary group only, the counter is empty. When I query the same user with a command manually - the counter works.

If a user is a member of any other group, then the script works fine.

***As an example:***

```
...
foreach ($user in $users)
    {
        $SAM = $user.SamAccountName
        $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $SAM | select name
        $SAM
        $groups.count
...
```

***Output***

```
SomeUser
2
SomeUser1
SomeUser2
SomeUser3
37
...
```

***If I query SomeUser1 manually***

```
(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity SomeUser1 | select name).count
1
```

Comment: Wrap it in an array `@(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $SAM)`  then you ensure there is always a `.Count` property ;)

Comment: That helped. Thank you. I knew that I'm missing something small.

Comment: What you're seeing is a _bug_ in _Windows PowerShell_, which has since been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+ : PowerShell is designed to report an intrinsic `.Count` property for _any_ scalar object that doesn't have a type-native property of that name, with value `1`, for unified handling of collections and scalars. In Windows PowerShell, this unexpectedly doesn't work for `[pscustomobject]` instances, such as returned by `Select-Object`. The workaround is to use `@(...).Count`  - so as ensure that the value of interest is treated as an _array_ (which has a type-native `.Count` property).